# Java threading - worker threads changing hashmap of its boss

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a class (Server) which listens for requests and once a request is made, starts a new thread which handles it. The handler thread will read in the data, store it into a hashmap and finish. I have put the hashmap in the server class as there can be multiple handler threads reading in the data as and when it comes in.

I'm confused whether this is the correct approach as in order to alter/access the hashmap, I'd have to write getters & setters and pass in the Server class to each and every worker thread. Some example code to try and describe my query:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
        private HashMap<String, Integer> data;

    public void run() {
       while(true) {
            Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
            Handler h = new Handler(s);
            Thread t = new Thread(h);
            t.start();
       }
   }
}

public class Handler implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        //read in data from socket
        data.put(d); //access the hashmap and insert data in
    } 

}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you use concurrenthashmap as you are using multiple threads otherwise you may run into some odd errors. This will handle all the synchronised access to the hashmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is fine, but you should either use a [`ConcurrentMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html), or `synchronize` on the map. The first approach is better since synchronized collections are [optimized in order to avoid blocking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) whenever it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Javier, I've changed the type in my code. I'm still wondering whether it's good practice to pass the server thread to the handler thread to add the data since multiple handler threads can hold the same server thread.

Comment: In that case why not just pass an instance of the hashmap to the handler, as thats the only object you require.

Comment: Good point. Would the ConcurrentMap be updated in the server thread when it's been changed in the handler thread?

Comment: Yes, as long as you use a concurrent container or explicit syncronization, changes made by the handler will be visible in the other threads.